# In Java, when is a "do while" loop the only option?

Tags: java, while-loop, do-while

Is there ever a situation where you *must* use a `do while` loop?  Is it an accepted practice? It seems like it is equivalent to a plain `while` loop except that its first iteration happens before checking the conditional, if that is even true.

```
int i = 3;
while ( i > 0 ) {  // runs 3 times
    i--;
}
```

vs

```
int j = 3;
do {
    j --;
} while ( j > 0 ); // runs 3 times
```

The same?

EDIT:  I have seen the java doc, but
the example in the java docs doesn't look like it requires that the particular routine inside of the do while loop must be run in the do while loop instead of inside of a regular while loop!

Comment: "It seems like it is equivalent to a plain while loop except that its first iteration happens before checking the conditional, if that is even true." You got it right ! Look at this :

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/while.html

Comment: You never *must* do anything.  There's always another technique to make something work when dealing with control flow.

Comment: @Sotirios Delimanolis A little edit to your statement. "At least once regardless of the condition".

Comment: In your examples, the condition is true initially, therefore `while-do-while-...` is equivalent to `do-while-do-...` . try init value `0` instead of `3`, you'll see the difference.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Is there ever a situation where you *must* use a `do while` loop?

No: every `do`-`while` loop *can* be written as a `while`-loop by running the body once before the loop begins. However, there are certainly cases where it makes more sense to use the `do`-`while` construct (i.e. if you always want the loop to iterate at least once), which is why it exists in the first place.

> Is it an accepted practice?

If you use it appropriately, then yes absolutely.

> It seems like it is equivalent to a plain `while` loop except that its first iteration happens before checking the conditional, if that is even true.

That's right. You can read more about `do`-`while` in its [tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/while.html).

Answer (score 2):

This example maybe help you be clearer:

```
int i = 3;

System.out.print("while:    ");
while (--i > 0){
    System.out.print("x");
}

System.out.print("\ndo-while: ");

int j = 3;
do
{
    System.out.print("x");
}while (--j > 0);
```

This prints

```
while:    xx
do-while: xxx
```

Answer (score 1):

A real time example.
    There is a contest with 5 level.
    In each level if you score 100 you can proceed to next level.
    Less code for do while, but not for while.

```
boolean playContest()
{//do while
    int level = 1;
    int score;
    do
    {
        score = 0;
        score = play();
    }while(score>99 && level++<6)
    if(level>4 && score>99)
        isWinner = true;
    else
        isWinner = false;
    return isWinner;
}

boolean playContest()
{//while
    int level = 1;
    int score;
    while(level <6)
    {
        score = 0;
        score = play();
        if(score < 100)
            break;
        level++;
    }
    if(level>4 && score>99)
        isWinner = true;
    else
        isWinner = false;
    return isWinner;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

basic difference between `while` and `do-while` is do while will be executed at least once.

when `do-while` is best option?

in case when you want to execute some actions till you meet condition, of course you could achieve same thing by using `while` but early termination of loop with break, is nasty and ugly solution

Answer (score 0):

When you want to execute the statement inside do for at least once, then you can go for it.

[Directly from Docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/while.html)

> The difference between do-while and while is that do-while evaluates its expression at the bottom of the loop instead of the top. Therefore, the statements within the do block are always executed at least once,

```
do {
     statement(s)
} while (expression);
```

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no time a do-while loops is the only option, it is used for convenience when you do not want to repeat code.